How to programmatically to go to a paragraph in Word 2016
I have a large document that I created, and some of the paragraphs are quite large.  Now I want to programmatically loop through each paragraph, and if a paragraph has too many words, then I want to go to that paragraph so that I can manually break it up or simplify it.
Looping through the paragraphs is not a problem; getting the number of words for each paragraph is not a problem.
But going to that paragraph is insanely difficult.
Much of the examples around the internet suggest this code:
Sub GotoParagraph10()
     Dim paragraphNumber as Integer

     paragraphNumber = 10

     Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToParagraph, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=paragraphNumber

End Sub

This code tries to go to paragraph 10.  The problem is that wdGoToParagraph is not defined in the WdGotoItem list - despite wide reference to this item.  This does show up in Intellisense, and when used at runtime, the constant resolves to -1 and the code thinks I'm trying to go to a bookmark, not a paragraph number.
Ok, so I got it - I can't use this constant.  How, then, do I programmatically go to a specific paragraph?

Thanks everyone, all of your methods work.

Try this out
Public Sub SelectParagraphByIndex(Index As Long)
    Dim Paragraph As Word.Paragraph
    Dim i         As Long
    
    For Each Paragraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        i = i + 1
        If i = Index Then
            Paragraph.Range.Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub

'Call from here
Public Sub SelectTester()
    SelectParagraphByIndex 10
End Sub



Use Paragraphs(N) to access the Nth paragraph.

Sub Dmeo()
    With ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(5).Range
        Debug.Print "Start: " & .Start
        Debug.Print "End: " & .End
        Debug.Print "Chars Count: " & Len(.Text) - 1
        ' Select the paragraph
        .Select
        ' Your code to manipuldate the paragraph
    End With
End Sub


The first argument of Goto is one of the WdGoToItem constants. There isn't wdGoToParagraph.

Microsoft documentation:

WdGoToItem enumeration (Word)



Selection isn't an efficient way to handle it, but you may use it.

Sub demo()
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    Selection.Move wdParagraph, 4  ' jump to the start point of 5th para.
    Selection.Expand wdParagraph
End Sub


As you said "Looping through the paragraphs is not a problem; getting the number of words for each paragraph is not a problem" I assume you already have code that is looping through the paragraphs collection and testing for a condition.
In which case going to the paragraph that meets your condition is insanely simple.
For each para in doc.Paragraphs
    If condition is met Then
        para.Range.Select
        exit for
    End If
Next para

